# How to make services node output of file to use external URL instead of public:// URI

Tags: files, services

I've got a basic web service defined in Drupal that returns JSON describing existing nodes on the server. Contained in the output is the key-value pair:

```
"uri":"public://audio_snippets/01 Australias.m4a"
```

Is there a way for the client website that consumes this service to convert the `public://` URI into something a browser can actually download, like http://www.mywebservice.com/audio_snippets/01Australias.m4a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [parse_url](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

Like

```
<?php
$url = file_create_url($field[0]['uri']);
$url = parse_url($url);
$path = $url['path'];
?>
```

OR  [file_create_url](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_create_url/7)

```
$usablepath = file_create_url($filesyspath);
```

OR

```
$path = str_replace('public:/', variable_get('file_public_path', 'sites/default/files'), $uri);
```

Comment: The problem is that the client website doesn't use Drupal and can't access those methods.

Ideally, there would be an easy way on the Drupal service site to alter what gets output by the default node retrieve service to include the URL as you've suggested above, but I'm not sure if there's a hook for modifying that.

Comment: @ChristopherMillward see my edit.

Comment: Fantastic, that'll do it!